# Android glGenTextures returns invalid IDs

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures

We develop a game for android, and everything works great on many devices. But yesterday we have tested the game on Samsung Galaxy Tab P1000 and have a problem.

The glGenTextures function returns invalid IDs, for example:
100271,
315638026,
534244737,
1505553220,
-1563003837

It is very strange. We have tried to create textures both in onSurfaceCreated and onDrawFrame functions, and have the same result. If we replace glGenTextures function with our own implementation based on counter, everything work!

Do anyone know what is happening?

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think that those are invalid IDs?

Texture IDs are GLuint, i.e. unsigned, so you certainly got no negative number there. And there's no requirement on OpenGL texture IDs to be monotonic and dense.

Comment: I have never seen such IDs, therefore I have decided that they are invalid. Usually I get IDs like 0, 1, 2, 3 ... 100 and more.

So you think that this strange IDs could be valid and everything is ok?

Comment: Our graphics engine can not handle such IDs and crashes on first negative ID. Yes this is our problem and we need to fix it.

So will fix it and then see how it works. Looks like you are right and it is just unusual IDs and nothing more.

Comment: Yes those "strange" IDs are valid, as far as the OpenGL specification goes. As I said, there's no requirement on monotony and density. Actually I think those IDs may be hashes of some sort (or maybe pointers, but that would be really crazy). Never make any assumptions on the form of opaque handles, like OpenGL names.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved the issue:

```
IntBuffer t = IntBuffer.allocate(1);
gl.glGenTextures(1, t);
int texture_id = t.get(0);
gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture_id);
```

Or, you can implement your own texture counter by creating a static int, and increment it every time you create a texture.

Comment: Sounds like the road to random failures to me, don't see why the API would randomly stop working